# saving the request.inputstream data in the doPost method

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

In class `A` (extending  `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet`) I declared an arraylist (`outputList`) variable and within its `doPost` method I am calling the `request.getInputStream()` method and added that stream to the outputList.

In another class I am accessing the same arraylist that I declared in `A`. But I could not get the inputstream that i added into the list. I am only getting the empty message on calling `outputList.get(index)`.

Here is the code:

```
Class A
{

ArrayList result;

 public A(ArrayList al)
{
    result = al;
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { 
   result.add(request.getInputStream)

}

Class B{
    ArrayList result;
    public B(ArrayList al){
    result = al;
}

public void retreive(){
   retreiveing the elements in the result arraylist using an iterator.
}
}
```

i am passing the same arraylist to both A and B. But within the retreive method in B when i tried to read the elements of the arraylist, they don't have any data in all input stream messges.

Comment: can you post a code snippet to understand it correctly.

Comment: Class A { ArrayList result; public A (ArrayList)}

Comment: sorry... i posted the sample code...

Answer (score 1):

You aren't really passing the concrete request body around, but only a pointer to it (which is in this particular case under the covers a network socket). So, when it get read elsewhere, or when you're reading it *after* the particular request has been processed, then it won't contain anything anymore. It'll return `-1` or be already closed.

You need to read it into a `byte[]` and pass that around instead.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
InputStream input = request.getInputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > -1;)
    output.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

byte[] bytes = output.toByteArray();
// Now store bytes in your `ArrayList`.
```

You only need to be aware that this way the POST requests cannot be processed by your servlet anymore, because you've consumed anything which the client has submitted. The client ain't going to resend the very same request multiple times. You'd need to make a copy of it. How to achieve this depends on the functional requirement which you didn't tell anything about in your question. Perhaps there are other/better ways, such as just logging the `request.getParameterMap()` instead.